# Get error on Ads load

Tags: android, android-layout, ads

When ap is loaded and try to request ad, get this error.

```
10-18 22:48:23.634: E/Ads(3776): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined (http://media.admob.com/:1)
10-18 22:48:23.634: E/Web Console(3776): Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined at http://media.admob.com/:1
```

I am using code which google has for example

```
public class Banner extends Activity {
private AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

String admob_publisher_id = "pub-blahblahblah";
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, admob_publisher_id);

TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
layout.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
adView.isActivated();
adView.isEnabled();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
if (adView != null) {
adView.destroy();
}
super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Also I try to use following, but no effect.

```
(new Thread() { 
public void run() { 
Looper.prepare(); 
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest()); 
} 
}).start();
```

In my main Table Layout I also use code from google example. Its show adview on layout.

So, how can I fix this kind of problem?